# Checking out a Github PR and then pulling updates?

Tags: bash, git, github, git-bash

I wrote a little bash script to check out PRs on the fly with:

`co URL`

```
co() {
    set $1
    git fetch upstream
    git checkout pr/${1##*/}
}
```

Once I am checked out on the branch, I'm wondering the best way to easily pull updates from the creators source branch.

For example:

UserA opens a PR into upstream master. I use this script to checkout the pull request, but UserA pushes an update. How can I pull any future updats?

Comment: What is `set $1` intended to do here? (What it *actually* does in practice is discard all your arguments after `$1`, then take what *is* in `$1`, break it up on spaces or characters in `IFS`, and expand each word resulting from that splitting operation as a glob; that's not usually a helpful set of behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple modification, assuming your PRs are all expected to be on `upstream` (as the existing code assumes) might be:

```
co() {
    git fetch upstream || return
    git checkout --track "pr/${1##*/}" || return
    git merge "upstream/pr/${1##*/}"
}
```

That's if you want to preserve any local changes you may have made, though force-pushes by others to the PR branch may mess things up a bit. If you just want to reset the branch to the remote one, discarding any local changes:

```
co() {
    git fetch upstream || return
    git checkout --track "pr/${1##*/}" || return
    git reset --hard "upstream/pr/${1##*/}"
}
```

...or, to put local changes *on top of* remote ones rather than discarding them outright:

```
co() {
  git fetch upstream || return
  git checkout --track "pr/${1##*/}" || return
  git rebase "upstream/pr/${1##*/}"
}
```

---

**That there's no one right way to do this is probably a good hint that git upstream did the right thing by *not* making it all one built-in command: Human judgment is appropriate to decide the right action based on the scenario at hand.**